# Iterate array with animation and conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, setinterval

I want to iterate (using `setIterval`) an an array of string like that:

```
const colors = ['all', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
```

The result is:

```
console.log('all') 
console.log('red')    // after 20 sec
console.log('blue')   // after 10 sec
console.log('green')  // after 10 sec
console.log('yellow') // after 10 sec
```

But I have to consider also a random number: during the iteration, I may or may not want to show that color (this is related to single color (`red`, `blue`, `green`, `yellow`) not `all`). 
This depends on a certain condition that we can consider a random number in this simplified example:

```
if(Math.random() >= 0.5)
    showTheColor
else
    doesntShowTheColor
```

I simulate an example:

```
start animation
  show color all for 20 seconds

coin throw for color red = 0.7
  show color red for 10 seconds

coin throw for color blue = 0.4
  /

coin throw for color green = 0.1
  /

coin throw for color yellow = 0.8
  show color yellow for 10 seconds

show color all for 20 seconds

coin throw for color red = 0.2
  /

coin throw for color blue = 0.3
  /

coin throw for color green = 0.78
  show color green for 10 seconds

coin throw for color yellow = 0.5
  show color yellow for 10 seconds

show color all for 20 seconds

coin throw for color red = 0.6
  show color red for 10 seconds

coin throw for color blue = 0.7
  show color blue for 10 seconds

coin throw for color green = 0.4
  /

coin throw for color yellow = 0.1
  /

show color all for 20 seconds

coin throw for color red = 0.2
  /

coin throw for color blue = 0.1
  /

coin throw for color green = 0.3
  /

coin throw for color yellow = 0.15
  /

// NB: doesn't show color all for 20 seconds because all the previous colors are null. If I showed all for 20 sec, I would have a total of 40 sec of all and that's not what I want
coin throw for color red = 0.5 
  show color red for 10 seconds
```

Here is a piece of my code:

```
const INTERVAL_ALL = 20 // sec
const INTERVAL_SINGLE = 10 // sec

export class Animation extends React.Component {
  interval = null
  i = -1
  colors: string[]

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.colors = ['all', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
    this.startPlaying()
  }

  startPlaying = () => {
    this.interval = window.setInterval(() => this.updateColor(), INTERVAL * 1000) // which interval?
  }

  // where do I put conditions and how?
  updateColor() {
    this.i = this.i === this.colors.length - 1 ? 0 : this.i + 1
    const color = this.colors[this.i]
    this.doSomethingWithColor(color)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  doSomethingWithColor(color) {
    console.log(color)
  }

  render() {
    return (...)
  }
}
```

The code is a simplified version, it doesn't take into account the different types of timing and conditions.
I need help

Thanks a lot

Comment: `INTERVAL * 1000` will not give you a variable interval, the first time you call `setInterval`, the current value of `INTERVAL * 1000` will be taken and the timeout will be set to that number. It will not change when `INTERVAL` changes.

Comment: @VLAZ I know, for these reasons I'm asking help

Comment: should a coin toss occur after a Math.random < 0.5 right away or should the interval be spent once more before the toss?

Comment: @beth just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps you out, you can probably leverage the changeColor() function into your code.

Comment: If `Math.random() < 0.5` then the color should be skipped

Comment: skipped - yes. But should a new color be picked RIGHT AWAY, or should the attempt for it occur after the '10' or '20' second timeouts?

Comment: Aaah ok. It should be picked a new color right away

Comment: got it. edited my code to fit this.

Answer (score 1):

possibly you're looking for something like this:

Keeping it relatively simply, here's a sandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bardeen-7rxmh

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    colors: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"],
    currentColor: "red",
    currentIndex: 0,
    colorWasSkipped: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeColor();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { currentIndex, colorWasSkipped } = this.state;

    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.changeColor();
      },
      currentIndex === 0 && !colorWasSkipped
        ? "20000"
        : colorWasSkipped
        ? 0
        : "10000"
    );
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    const { colors, currentIndex } = this.state;
    const randomNumber = Math.random();

    const newColor =
      currentIndex < colors.length - 1 ? colors[currentIndex + 1] : colors[0];

    const newIndex = currentIndex < colors.length - 1 ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;

    if (randomNumber >= 0.5) {
      console.log(randomNumber + " changed " + newColor);
      this.setState({
        currentColor: newColor,
        currentIndex: newIndex,
        colorWasSkipped: false
      });
    } else {
      console.log(randomNumber + " skip " + newColor);
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: newIndex,
        colorWasSkipped: true
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const color = this.state.currentColor;
    return <div style={{ height: "200px", background: `${color}` }} />;
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions. If a color is skipped, we immediately try a new color and if its random number is less than 0.5, we skip it as well. The cycle continues until we get a number greater than or equal to 0.5, then we display that color for 10 seconds, unless we are back at index 0, where we display that color for 20 seconds instead.

Comment: Thanks, but in this code the interval is always 2 seconds, right?

Comment: @beth  Right, you can change it to 10 seconds, I just did that to show you that it works a bit faster. waiting 10 seconds for each change is a long time. Check out the sandbox to see it in action. :)

Comment: No ok, but I would like that `all` (`red` in your example) should stay for 20 sec, and other colors for 10 seconds. Intervals are different

Comment: Ok, it works, just one last request. Is it possible to make sure that if `randomNumber <= 0.5`, then you keep trying until you find a color to show?
Because now, there are stages in which a color is shown more than necessary

Comment: @beth, yup! I just updated that in my sandbox. try it out, I got the console.logs to prove it  :) If it skips, we immediately try a new color and if random number isnt greater than 0.5 in that attempt, we skip again immediately until we get it above 0.5.

Comment: @beth Wow that was probably one of the harder problems I've solved on StackOverflow. Thanks for the challenge :) . If you found this solution helpful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a React guy per se, but let me know if this is what you are looking for. Also, you did not mention what the behaviour should be if after a coin toss nothing should happen - should we toss the coin once more right away or should we still wait for the interval?

```js
const INTERVAL_ALL = 20 // sec
const INTERVAL_SINGLE = 10 // sec

export class Animation extends React.Component {
  // interval = null - not needed, timeout will do
  activeInterval: number;
  i = 1 // should start at index 1, right after 'all'
  colors: string[]
  currentColor: string;

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.colors = ['all', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
    this.currentColor = this.colors[0] // set current color to 'all' at beginning
    this.activeInterval = INTERVAL_ALL; // animation starts with all, so 20 secs.
    this.startPlaying();
  }

  startPlaying = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.attemptColorChange();
    }, this.activeInterval * 1000) //
  }

  // where do I put conditions and how?
  pickNewColor(): string {
    this.i = this.i % this.colors.length
    const newColor = this.colors[this.i++]
    return newColor;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  attemptColorChange() {
    const newColor = this.pickNewColor();
    const shouldChangeColor = Math.random() >= 0.5
    if (shouldChangeColor) {
      if (newColor === 'all') {
        this.activeInterval = INTERVAL_ALL;
      } else {
        this.activeInterval = INTERVAL_SINGLE;
      }
      this.currentColor = newColor;
      this.startPlaying();
    }
    else {
      this.attemptColorChange();
    }
  }

  render() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with `the behaviour should be if after a coin toss nothing should happen`?

Comment: I just asked the question in a comment just below your post, maybe answer there so others can see it as well. Thanks.